How can I automatically reload a Chromium tab when I get a connection error?
I use Chromium on a Raspberry PI4. My VPN often changes IP, so sometimes I get this error (ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED). And when it happens, the tab remains stuck indefinitely on the error page without trying to reload. (Needless to say, that error is always solvable after refreshing at most a few seconds later).
The problem is that usually I'm not looking at the tab because it does automatic stuff while I'm afk, so I need the browser to try to reload the tab indefinitely in presence of any connection error until the connection returns without my presence.
when I discovered this error, the tab was stuck like this for at least an hour
So, what's the best way to make this happen? Thanks in advance.
(what I tried)
I tried to see if Chromium or the closely related Chrome had built in solutions for automatic offline page reloading.
Apparently Chrome used to have years ago a flag exactly for this (offline-auto-reload) but it's not available anymore. Not sure about Chromium.
There are extensions in the Chrome Store that refresh tabs periodically, but they don't seem to be selective towards connection errors. I could use one of them but first I want to ask if there is a better way.
Using an older version of Chromium is also not an option because my scripts would break with versions as recent as of 2023.
